# fetch data from mongodb with template pug using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

Currently I have a problem with fetching data. I want to get data from  database and print it with pug template
Here is code from my index.js where I get data from collection and putting in to array.

```
//Printing a lesson
 router.get('/getLesson', function(req,res, next){
     var resultArray = [];
     mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
         assert.equal(null,err);
         var cursor = db.collection('lesson-data').find();
         cursor.forEach(function(doc, err){
             assert.equal(null, err);
             resultArray.push(doc);
         }, function(){
             db.close();
             res.render('lessons', {item: resultArray});
         });
     });
 });

//Inserting a lesson
router.post('/lessonInsert', function(req,res,next){
    var lesson = {
        topic: req.body.topic,
        description: req.body.description,
        language: req.body.language,
        level: req.body.level
    };

    mongo.connect(url,function(err, db){
        assert.equal(null,err);
        db.collection('lesson-data').insertOne(lesson, function(err, result){
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Lesson inserted');
            db.close();
        })
    })
});
```

There I was trying to print my array.

```
.container(action='/getLesson')        
  each item in resulArray
    li #{item.topic}: #{item.description}: #{item.language}: #{item.level}
```

Any tips, help?

Answer (score 1):

When you do the following:

```
res.render('lessons', {item: resultArray})
```

you are actually passing the variable `resultArray` named as `item` to you pug template. So the iteration would be:

```
.container(action='/getLesson')        
  each element in item
    li #{element.topic}: #{element.description}: #{element.language}: #{element.level}
```

Comment: When I put this part of code .container(action='/getLesson')        
  each element in item
    li #{element.topic}: #{element.description}: #{element.language}: #{element.level}, I get an error: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory. Any ideas why?